# Listview out of memory exception in viewholder

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-viewholder

Hello I'm trying to display a range of images within a ListView but when I run the application it runs out of memory, which is very strange as when testing it last night it worked perfect and when returning to it this morning it know longer wishes to play ball. I'm using a ViewHolder pattern and I was wondering if someone could spot my mistake?

LiqAdapter

```
public class LiqAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Liq_String> {

List<Liq_String> lstLiq;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public LiqAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Liq_String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    lstLiq = objects;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    ViewHolderLiq viewholder;

    if (view == null){

        viewholder = new ViewHolderLiq();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_winelist, null);
        viewholder.liqImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineImage);
        viewholder.liqName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineName);
        viewholder.liqDes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineDes);
        viewholder.liqPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.winePrice);

        view.setTag(viewholder);
    }else{
        viewholder = (ViewHolderLiq) view.getTag();
    }

    Liq_String wine = lstLiq.get(position);

    viewholder.setDataIntoViewHolderLiqueurs(wine);

    return view;
}
}
```

---

Viewholder

```
public class ViewHolderLiq {

public ImageView liqImage;
public TextView liqName;
public TextView  liqDes;
public TextView  liqPrice;

public void setDataIntoViewHolderLiqueurs(Liq_String liqString){
    liqImage.setImageResource(liqString.getIcon_liq());
    liqName.setText(liqString.getLiqName());
    liqDes.setText(liqString.getLiqdes());
    liqPrice.setText(liqString.getLiqPrices());
}
}
```

---

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 26620312 byte allocation   with 4194304 free bytes and 11MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
at wine.entity.ViewHolderLiq.setDataIntoViewHolderLiqueurs(ViewHolderLiq.java:20)
at wine.Adapter.LiqAdapter.getView(LiqAdapter.java:73)
```

Comment: @Alexander indeed indeed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CRASH:**
As your stacktrace says:

> "java.lang.**OutOfMemoryError**: Failed to allocate a 26620312 byte
>   allocation   with 4194304 free bytes and 11MB until OOM"

- you try to display a huge bitmap on your view. Your phone doesn't like it.

**Two solutions:**

- reduce the dimensions of your image, use a smaller image... and
  retry!
- or set `android:largeHeap="true"` in your Manifest, in your application
  tags. It will increase your heap size and avoid the **OutOfMemory**
  error, but your application will probably lag.

Comment: @james glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 26620312 byte
>   allocation   with 4194304 free bytes and 11MB until OOM

**[OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)**

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector. OutOfMemoryError objects may be constructed by the
>   virtual machine/Device as if suppression were disabled and/or the
>   stack trace was not writable.

### Reasons

You are dealing with large bitmaps and loading all of them at run time.

```
liqImage.setImageResource(liqString.getIcon_liq()); // Here is problem .Size too large
```

### Solution

At first, Please reduce image size.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is to big, for reducing it this is a good solution:

http://android-coding.blogspot.hu/2011/06/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html